# Whem i output this code nothing comes out someone explain?

Tags: python

I have found the following code on the internet and it is meant to output the positions of the words in the list:

```
mylist
```

But it is not working, here is the code:

```
mylist="example string with spaces"
sentencelist=[]
for z in mylist.split(" "):
    sentencelist.append(z)
wordlist=[]
for z in range(len(sentencelist)):
    if sentencelist[z] not in wordlist:
        wordlist.append(sentencelist[z])

wordpositions=[]
for i in range (len(sentencelist)):
    for o in range(len(wordlist)):
        if sentencelist[i]==wordlist[o]:
                wordpositions.append(o+1)

wordlist=str(wordlist)
wordpositions=str(wordpositions)

inputFile=open("sentence.txt","w")
inputFile.write(wordlist)
inputFile.write("\n")
inputFile.write(wordpositions)
inputFile.close()
```

No error message comes out but it also doesn't work. Can someone expalin

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing comes out"? It is not supposed to generate any console output, only a file called `sentence.txt`. Did the file get created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the script does successfully write a file `sentence.txt` with the content of `wordlist` and `wordpositions`.

If you want to have these printed out to console, as well, add:

```
print(wordlist)
print(wordpositions)
```